# Can't use static files via url_for in my Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I learn Flask with YouTube tutorials. And every time (now it's my 3rd Flask series) I have the same exact problem - files from static folder don't do what they should do when I use **url_for** like this:.

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
```

I mean **.js** doesn't do anything, **.css** doesn't change elements' style, images do not appear on the page. And debugger doesn't show any errors. But when I use **url_for** to redirect a user to another route - it works perfectly! So I have no idea how to fix this. I use macbook, so maybe it is some problem with access to local files?

P.S. I don't show any code because it's not a typo in my code. Even if I copy-past the code from the tutors' github, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you specifying a static folder on app instantiation? E.g. `app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')`?

Comment: Please [edit] to show your files and folders directory structure. Maybe you put your js and css files in the wrong folder. Flask expects them to be in specific locations, unless you set the `static_folder` parameter.

Comment: Also, I recommend going through official docs on serving static files with Flask, like this: https://exploreflask.com/en/latest/static.html. I have nothing against Youtube Tutorials, but they tend to not show the complete details of the app.

Comment: Do the logs show that the .js and .css files are being requested? If not, the problem is in the HTML in the template.

Comment: @bernie no. I thought the first attribute I pass to url_for is the name of the static folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) is the endpoint name and `'static'` is a special endpoint name to refer to the [Static Files](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#static-files) of your application:

> Just create a folder called `static` in your package or next to your
>   module and it will be available at `/static` on the application.
>
> To generate URLs for static files, use the special 'static' endpoint
>   name:
>
> ```
> url_for('static', filename='style.css')
> ```
>
> The file has to be stored on the filesystem as `static/style.css`.

So, given this:

```
<link ... href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
```

And assuming you create your Flask instance like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Make sure your app file/folder structure is like this:

```
.
├── app.py
├── static
│   └── styles.css
└── templates
    └── app.html
```

If you are organizing your JS and CSS files like this:

```
.
├── app.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── styles.css
│   └── js
│       └── app.js
└── templates
    └── app.html
```

Then you have to appropriately change the arguments to `url_for` like this:

```
<link ... href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/styles.css') }}">
```

If you named the `static` folder to something else (ex. "assets"), then you have to specify that new name to the `static_folder` parameter when [creating the Flask instance](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=flask#flask.Flask).

```
app = Flask(__name__,
            static_folder="assets")
```

You can also check the Flask debugger logs that the static files are accessed correctly:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2019 20:30:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2019 20:30:44] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Or your browser's debugger/inspection tools that it is indeed downloading the files correctly:

[image]